# Proftpd user permissions issue

Tags: permissions, ftp, proftpd

I just installe proftpd on Ubuntu 15.04 and it works fine i made a permission setting for my ftp user called "ftp" there has the dir "/home/ftp/" but i have a problem because i have a folder inside my home folder "/home/ftp/public_html/ that it seems to my permissions dosen't have any effect on because in "/home/ftp" i got the right permissions as i wrote but in "/home/ftp/public_html" i can download, upload. delete etc. why would it not work? you can see my permissions here

```
<Directory /home/ftp>
Umask 022 022
AllowOverwrite off
 <Limit LOGIN>
    AllowUser ftp
    DenyALL
 </Limit>
 <Limit ALL>
    Order Allow,Deny
    AllowUser ftp
    Deny ALL
</Limit>
 <Limit MKD STOR DELE XMKD RNRF RNTO RMD XRMD>
AllowUser ftp
Deny ALL
</Limit>
</Directory>
```